# Homepage with multitouch login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, touch

I'd like to create a homepage based on touch. So, for example, if the user touches the screen with 5 fingers, like in the image (the green circles, see below) it will redirect the user to a specific homepage but if he touches in other pattern(the red circles) it will show an 'Login Failed, Try Again' alert. It doesn't matter where the user touches as long as it is inside the square.

The main idea is to determine the user's finger locations and redirect him to another page, 
the login idea is just an example.

Is there a way to do this using HTML and JavaScript, because I want it to be an iOS homepage?

[image: example layout]

Comment: Plain HTML + JS wouldn't make any sense, since JS is uncompiled and anyone could read the correct password from your code.

Comment: The point is determining the touches to redirect the user to a specific homepage ... the picture above is just an example of the usage ... but thanks anyway ..

Comment: I know, but if you want to check this client-side, you would need to hardcode your password/touch locations in the .js, visible to everyone.

Comment: I understand that the security will be weak at the moment.
but in the time being it doesn't matter that much.
cos i will be using it just to redirect from page to another.

Comment: Why do you need a password at all then?

Comment: It's not a password but I want to use the different patterns to take the user to different home pages (instead of clicking links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to bind to the touch events for the element you wish the user to touch in. These events are touchstart, touchmove and touchend (well and touchcancel). On the event the co-ordinates of finger positions are given in an array (well actually three - see link at bottom for which array or arrays to access for which events/scenarios). You can then use these co-ordinates to calculate the shape.

Here is an example for a two fingers using jquery (not essential).

```
#JQuery
$('#myID').bind("touchstart", function(event) {
  var finger1PosX = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
  var finger2PosX = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[1].pageX;
});
```

This assumes at least two fingers are pressed, which is a bad assumption.

Here is a good tutorial/discussion:
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

You might also want to prevent scrolling and other gestures in this div using event.preventDefault.

Also note support for multi touch events on android differs between versions (I know you were asking about ios).

Comment: Thanks! this tutorial is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

No, for password-secured pages you also will need serverside processing.

Your HTML page will include a (invisible) form which will be updated with coordinates from the touch event handlers. Then, after a given time or when a condition (like: 5 coords registered) is fulfilled, you will submit the form. Lateron you also may transform this into an AJAX service, but there's no difference.

The server application will then need to analyze the touch pattern, and send a fail message or a success notice with login cookies.

Comment: your Idea is good if I was going actually to do a real login,
I'll keep it in mind for the future usage ..
Thanks

Comment: So what are you looking for? A way to get the 5 coords? Or an (javascript) algorithm to check a set of coords against one or more patterns?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to:  1st check if 5 fingers is touching the screen or not. (if the 1st is TRUE)2nd check the 5 fingers' coords... after that i can compare the coords and check the pattern then do some action.

Answer (score 2):

[jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) will get you in the right direction.

Comment: It is a really useful plugin.
but needs a little customize .. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can get the array of the touches (5 in your case) each of them with it's coordinate. From there it should be "easy" to determine what you want, it's just comparing the coordinates to your box's coordinates in a loop. See some tutorial here http://seb.ly/2011/04/multi-touch-game-controller-in-javascripthtml5-for-ipad/ or find hundred others on google

Comment: Thanks for the idea .. the thing i don't know is how to analyze which part of the screen the user touched and did he/she touched the screen with 5 fingers or not ..
after I do that I can start using your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a hidden table. which will also provide you a way to deal with error Torrance.

If you look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/ and the Touch enabled apps section this may help you in monitoring multi touch events

I would get a grid which would have a number of cells. (larger number of cells will = harder to crack password but also more prone to making it hard for users to login!)

Then if you have a Grid of 10x10 for example... (where 1 = users touch)

```
0010000000
0101000000
0101000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

you could then work out the relation between the 1s to see if it matches

Comment: But when the user can't see the table, he is likely to touch on/near a border - how would that be handled?

Comment: I agree with Bergi.
but thanks for the site I looks useful and I can borrow some codes from ..